# Changing the content of a div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function `ImageIndexing(type,data)` that will return a string according to the two variables. Than I have classes: `portoflioTitle`, `portfolioThumbnail`, `portoflioBig`; and I need to change their content, `src`, `id` accordingly to their `data-title`, `data-thumb` and `data-big`. Its really hard to explain, so let me try.

So:

1. After the page loads a function is executed.
2. First, the function changes the `innerHTML` (content) of all the `div`s with class `portfolioTitle`. It changes it trough the `ImageIndexing` function to which it passes `'title'` as the type and its `data-title` as the data. The `ImageIndexing` function will then return the string we need to change the `innerHTML` to. (can you understand it so far?)
3. It repeats the same with the other classes. With `portfolioThumbnail` it passes `'image'` as the type and its `data-thumb` as the data and than sets the returned string to its `src`. `portfolioBig` passes `'big'` and `data-big` and uses the string as its `id`.

Comment: I think I understand your situation, but what is your question?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: So far..I have nothing, because the function I was working on didn't work. And the question is how to do it. The hardest part is passing the data-x and than using the returned string as the innerHtml/etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: You should use .attr to get the value of the element. Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/tgccQ/2/) here

I am not sure what you really want, but from your comment I believe you want to know hwo to pass data-x and set the innerHTML of the corresponding div.

Below is just rough version, let us know if you have any questions.

```
   $('div.portoflioTitle').each (function(index) {

      $(this).html(ImageIndexing(this.title, $(this).attr('data-title')));

    });

    function ImageIndexing(type, data) {
       //do w.e you have to do and return

       return "<span>can return anything that you wanna set inside the div</span>";
    }
```

Comment: It's giving much more sense then my code did, but it doesn't quite work. My code  - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgccQ/)